# Disabling the websecurity of chrome browser

Tags: browser

I have one project on my localhost and to run that i need to disable the websecurity of my
chromebrowser. For that i run the below Command:-

C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security.

But my problem is every time i need to run this command in CMDprompt when i restart the project.

Is there any way that i can create the shortcut for chrome.exe and run directly with disabled websecurity.

If converting .exe to batch will work then let me know how can i execute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just downloading xammp https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html ? That way you don't need to bypass the security. You host your project inside your xammp folder.

Comment: Actually i have my Project's backend in Visual Studio 2013 and i am using windows azure for database. I wanted to turn my Application into SPA app using backbone.js and Marionette. For Client side i am using the netbeans as IDE and Wampserver for application hosting. Since the WebApi is on other platform like VS2013 i need to disable the websecurity of chrome everytime i run the application.

Comment: You could create a .bat file. with the command and the options in it but you may need to run it as administrator (vista+). But your problem may be due to cross domain policy. I would try to fix that instead.